# Rails SMTP error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, smtp, actionmailer

Trying to setup Mandril SMTP in my rails app.. when i go to register a new user I get the following error:

```
Net::SMTPFatalError in RegistrationsController#create

554 5.7.1 <nkeating@lion.lmu.edu>: Relay access denied
```

[The mandrill setup guide](http://help.mandrill.com/customer/portal/articles/456751-web-frameworks) says `"# In a controller: YourMailer.email_name.deliver"`.. im not sure how to configure this, i dont have anything in my registrations controller.

Full trace below

```
/Users/nelsonkeating/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:954:in `check_response'
/Users/nelsonkeating/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:923:in `getok'
/Users/nelsonkeating/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:866:in `rcptto'
/Users/nelsonkeating/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:847:in `block in rcptto_list'
/Users/nelsonkeating/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:845:in `each'
/Users/nelsonkeating/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:845:in `rcptto_list'
/Users/nelsonkeating/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:666:in `send_message'
mail (2.4.4) lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:145:in `block in deliver!'
/Users/nelsonkeating/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:526:in `start'
mail (2.4.4) lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:144:in `deliver!'
mail (2.4.4) lib/mail/message.rb:2034:in `do_delivery'
mail (2.4.4) lib/mail/message.rb:229:in `block in deliver'
actionmailer (3.2.3) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:414:in `block in deliver_mail'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionmailer (3.2.3) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:412:in `deliver_mail'
mail (2.4.4) lib/mail/message.rb:229:in `deliver'
devise (2.1.0) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:128:in `send_on_create_confirmation_instructions'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:420:in `_run__2902994895577254923__create__297803661615302062__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_create_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:268:in `create'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:344:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `block in create_or_update'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__2902994895577254923__save__297803661615302062__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:84:in `save'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in save'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block in save'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:252:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
devise (2.1.0) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:15:in `create'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__1577789481977373940__process_action__3613823028843665787__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:40:in `call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
rack-pjax (0.5.9) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
client_side_validations (3.1.4) lib/client_side_validations/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
remotipart (1.0.2) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:30:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:467:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__329187641558693815__call__297803661615302062__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have the ActionMailer smtp settings defined anywhere? You could put them in config/initializers/setup_mail.rb.

setup_mail.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
  :address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
  :port      => 587,
  :user_name => "MANDRILL_USERNAME",
  :password  => "MANDRILL_SMTP_PASS"

}
```

And in your config/environments/production.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
```